# How to always open expo web on http://localhost:19006 instead of host ip?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

By default, expo start the web app open using the `http://$hostIp:19006` (such as `192.168.1.10:19006` when your `$hostIp` is `192.168.1.10`).

The are restrictions when using `$hostIp`:

- we can't access camera
- we can't access position
- our backend need to declare host allowed to access it

For those reasons, we would like to always prioritize the `http://localhost:19006` to work in development (instead of `http://192.168.X.X:19006`

The teamwork with GitLab.

Is there a way I can configure it so the browser that opens uses that URL?

- SDK Version: 36
- Platforms: web

Answer (score 2):

Find `.expo` folder in your project directory. Open `packager-info.json` file and edit the ports to your liking. Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't make it default for all the git repositories developers, `.expo` is not versionned

Comment: And the down vote is for missing the question, I do not care about changing the port, I use 19006 already as in my question

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you mention git repo, or multiple developers, or the fact that you already use 19006...

Comment: Sorry but to me git is the current standard for SVN client, I stated `we would like` and I showed `localhost:19006` as my default address. If you use expo, you would know that it will open `$hostIp:19006`.

Comment: I didn't meant to make you fell upset, if you think my question is unclear, then ask for it. I will update it now. In all case, this should be close/deleted as it does not answer the original question. Thanks for understanding

Comment: The original question still doesn't point out that you want this change to be effective for anyone who clones or forks the project. In either case, if you want a certain change to be effective automatically for _anyone who works on the project_ then the config file that enforces that change will need to be versioned. There's no good way around that.

Comment: If I edit that file, change all ports, and run yarn start, it still uses the old ports, after the run my changes are gone. Tested on fresh install.